# Recursion on apply

Tags: r, recursion

I tried performing the following recursion:y[i]=y[i-1]+a[i] and I tried:

```
   apply(c(2:10),2,function(x) y[x]=y[x-1]+a[x])
```

But it did not work. Is there some other way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `sapply` on this occasion and also the `<<-` operator if you want to assign values to `y` inside the `sapply`. The following works:

Example data:

```
y    <- vector() #initiate a vector (can also simply do y <- 1 )
y[1] <- 1        #I suppose the first value will be provided
a    <- 20:30    #some random data for a
```

Solution:

```
#sapply works for vectors i.e. for your 2:10, c() is unnecessary btw
#<<- operator modifies the y vector outside the sapply according to the formula 
> sapply(c(2:10), function(x) {y[x] <<- y[x-1] + a[x]} )
[1]  22  44  67  91 116 142 169 197 226

#y looks like this after the assignments 
> y
 [1]   1  22  44  67  91 116 142 169 197 226
```

Comment: You could also try just `y[x-1] + a[x]` inside the `sapply` and store this into a variable i.e. without `y[x]  <<-`. It will be faster this way.

Comment: If I could do that then I think I could just do vector math (y[2:10]+a[1:9], the issue is the recursive element...

Comment: I see. If you want to assign values to your `y` then a for-loop might be faster since the sapply above does the same thing twice (once it updates y and once it stores the result in an output)

Comment: It was about 9 to 7 in terms of speed.

Comment: If you use `<<-` in `*apply`, you are using the wrong loop construct. Also, recursion is not a strength of the R language.

Answer (score 3):

This is faster:

```
c(0,cumsum(a[c(-1,-length(a))])) + 1
```

or equivalently:

```
c(0,cumsum(a[seq(2,10)])) + 1
```